# How to find the symmetry group of a vector field $x\partial_x+y\partial_y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I'm struggling with an exercise in Arnold's book about DEs, maybe someone could suggest a hint on how to solve it?

An exercise goes like this:

find the group of symmetries for a vector field $x\partial_x+y\partial_y$ on a plane with coordinates $(x,y).$ I know that rotations and homothetic transformations cenetred at the origin.

I was unable to prove that all symmetries are linear (i.e. generated by homotheties and rotation). I wrote down a system of PDEs to give conditions on diffeomorphism to preserve vector field, however, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hint: A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is affine (i.e. $f(\vec{x})=A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$) if and only if its Jacobian is constant. Can you use your PDE to show this?

Comment: @Kajelad, yes it basically says that, however, I'm not sure that your statement is correct. I think that if it is true, then Jacobian conjecture is trivial. Moreover, I think there is a counterexample to your statement, called Pinchuk's map. Maybe I'm getting you wrong((

Comment: By Jacobian, I mean the Jacobian *matrix*; i.e. all partial derivatives are constant. This can be proven with a computation starting with$$f(v)-f(u)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}f((1-t)u+tv)dt$$and then using chain rule.

Comment: @Kajelad, ah, yes, then it is quite obvious, thank you! Sorry for misunderstanding you((